# NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for true:TrueClass for mapping headers/creating CSVs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, pry

I'm downloading a bunch of CSVs in order to dump them into one big CSV to export. I am using Selenium/Ruby/Ruby-on-rails (?) in order to achieve this.

The problem I am currently having is I get a

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for true:TrueClass
Did you mean?  tap ``

for the following code:

```
def csv_creation(source)

      l_source = {'lead_source' => source.to_s}

      input_file = Dir.glob("path_to_file/name_of_files*.csv").last

      rows = CSV.open(input_file, headers: true).map(&:to_h)

      rows.each { |h| h.merge!(l_source) }

      headers = rows.first.keys

      rows.first.keys.each { |k| puts k }

      csv_response = CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << headers

        rows.each do |row|
          csv << row.values_at(*headers)
        end
      end

      File.open("#{source}.csv", "w") { |file| file.write(csv_response) }

      input_files = Dir.glob("#{source}*.csv")

      all_headers = input_files.reduce([]) do |all_header, file|
        header_line = File.open(file, &:gets)

        all_headers | CSV.parse_line(header_line)
      end

      CSV.open("out.csv", "a+") do |out|
        out << all_headers

        input_files.each do |file|
          CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|

            out << all_headers.map{ |header| row[header] }

          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Before I was told I had to run this on rails c and throw in a module, this code worked. I am not experienced in Ruby or RoR but obviously this shift has disrupted my code.

Random tidbits:

- "source" holds text gathered from a drop down menu
- The module in question was built by my host company so I am not entirely sure what it contains -- sorry.
- Rails c doesn't really give me the line number where this error is happening but I think it is happening in the second "map" so I printed out some of the lines to see if anything was off but nothing was. It's getting a "true" value from somewhere and I honestly don't know where. Everything should be a string.

Some insight would be appreciated.

Comment: are you running this in a local server?

Comment: I am running it locally, yes. @lacostenycoder

Comment: can you share an excerpt of one of the csvs?

Comment: it's worth installing a debugger gem such as pry and adding a breakpoint to check the value of your variables

Comment: @HerbertH : Your calculation of `all_headers` seems to be broken. In any case, your `all_headers` don't contain an Array. What is the single vertical bar in the expression `all_headers | CSV.parse_line(header_line)` supposed to do?

Comment: @HerbertH : Also, you never use you memo-object `all_header` inside the reduce block.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the bug now: As I commented, the

```
      all_headers = input_files.reduce([]) do |all_header, file|
         header_line = File.open(file, &:gets)
         all_headers | CSV.parse_line(header_line)
     end
```

is non-sense: Note that on the first execution of the do ... end block, all_headers is `nil`, because the variable has been defined, but not assigned. When you calculate `all_headers | CSV.parse_line(header_line)`, this is equivalent to `nil | [ ... something ...]`, and this evaluates to true. This is repeated on every iteration, and in the end, `all_headers` receives the value `true`.

I think you meant `all_header | CSV.parse_line(header_line)`